# Print attributes from two tags together

Tags: perl

I am using XML:twig to extract some attributes from an XML file using Perl;

Here is my code

```
use XML::Twig;
my $file = $ARGV[0];
$file =~ /(.+)\.xml/;
my $outfile = $1 . ".snp" ;
open my $out, '>', $outfile or die "Could not open file '$outfile' $!";
my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        'Rs/MergeHistory' => \&MergeHistory,
    }
);

$twig -> parsefile( "$file");

sub MergeHistory {
    my ($twig, $elt) = @_;
    print $out "\t";
    print $out "rs";
    print $out $elt->att('rsId'), ",";
    print $out "b";
    print $out $elt->att('buildId'), ",";
}
```

This print the following results:

```
rs56546490,b130,    rs386588736,b142
rs56546490,b130,    rs386588736,b142
```

What I want is to print each MergeHistory rsId and buildId together as the following:

```
rs56546490,rs386588736,   b130,b142
rs56546490,rs386588736,   b130,b142
```

Here is a part of the XML file which contains on two MergeHistory tags :

```
 <Rs rsId="98324" snpClass="snp" snpType="notwithdrawn"
  molType="genomic" genotype="true"bitField="050028000005130500030100"
    taxId="9606">
    <Het type="est" value="0.05" stdError="0.1547"/>
    <Validation byCluster="true" byOtherPop="true" byHapMap="true"
    by1000G="true">
        <otherPopBatchId>7179</otherPopBatchId>
    </Validation>
    <Create build="36" date="2000-09-19 17:02"/>
    <Update build="144" date="2015-05-07 10:52"/>
    <Sequence exemplarSs="491581208" ancestralAllele="C,C">
    <Seq5>
     ATAAGCAAATAACTGAAGTTTAATCAGTCTCCTCCCAGCAAGTGATATGCAACTGAGATTCC
     TTATGACACATCTGAACACTAGTGGATTTGCTTTGTAGTAGGAACAA
     GGTACATTCGCGGGATAAATGTGGCCAAGTTTTATCTGCTGCCAGGGCTTTCAAAT
     AGGTTGACCTGACAATGGGTCACCTCTGGGACTGA</Seq5>
        <Observed>C/T</Observed>
  <Seq3>AATTAGGAAGAGCTGGTACCTAAAATGAAAGATGCCCTTAAATTTCAGATTCACAATTTTTT
        TTTCTTAGTATAAGCATGTCCCATGTAATATCTGGGATATACTCATACCTT
        TAAAAATGTGCTCATTGTTTATCTGAAATTCACATTTTAACAGGGAACCATTGT
        TTTGTTATTGTTTATTGTTTTGTTTCTAAATAA</Seq3>
    </Sequence>
    <Ss ssId="1556770886" handle="1000GENOMES" batchId="1061891"
     locSnpId="PHASE3_chrY_229259" subSnpClass="snp" orient="reverse"
      strand="top" molType="genomic" buildId="144"
       methodClass="sequence" validated="by-submitter">
        <Sequence>
            <Seq5>TTTTAGGTACCAGCTCTTCCTAATT</Seq5>
            <Observed>A/G</Observed>
            <Seq3>TCAGTCCCAGAGGTGACCCATTGTC</Seq3>
        </Sequence>
    </Ss>
    <Assembly dbSnpBuild="144" genomeBuild="38.2"
    groupLabel="GRCh38.p2" current="true" reference="true">
        <Component componentType="contig" accession="NT_011875.13"
        chromosome="Y" start="11642902" end="21789280"
        orientation="fwd" gi="568801947" groupTerm="NC_000024.10"
        contigLabel="GCF_000001405.28">
            <MapLoc asnFrom="5341580" asnTo="5341580" locType="exact"
        alnQuality="1" orient="reverse" physMapInt="16984482"
       leftContigNeighborPos="5341579"rightContigNeighborPos="5341581"
       refAllele="G"/>
        </Component>
        <SnpStat mapWeight="unique-in-contig" chromCount="1"
         placedContigCount="1" unplacedContigCount="0" seqlocCount="1"
        hapCount="0"/>
    </Assembly>
    <RsLinkout resourceId="1" linkValue="3894"/>
    <RsLinkout resourceId="4" linkValue="60936"/>
    <RsLinkout resourceId="5" linkValue="23388839"/>
    <MergeHistory rsId="56546490" buildId="130"/>
    <MergeHistory rsId="386588736" buildId="142"/>
    <hgvs>NC_000024.9:g.19096363G&gt;A</hgvs>
    <hgvs>NC_000024.10:g.16984483G&gt;A</hgvs>
    <Frequency freq="0.0276" allele="A" sampleSize="1233"/>
</Rs>
```

Comment: Give us some valid XML and a better idea of how that maps to your desired output and we may be able to help

Comment: @Sobrique, thanks, I modified my code now. this is a part of my long code which I cannot post it because it is somehow long. Also, my XML file big too, for this I just added a part of it.

Comment: That still isn't valid XML. A subset is ok, but it must be valid.

Comment: @Sobrique, I added a subset

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`twig_handlers` is good for pre-processing XML, and most especially for discarding it as you go.

It's probably not what you want here though - it looks like what you're trying to do is:

- extract each 'MergeHistory' element from each 'Rs' element.
- Print the content reformatted.

So with that in mind - I think what you probably want is `findnodes` and `children`.

```
my $twig = XML::Twig->parsefile( $file );

foreach my $rs ( $twig->findnodes('//Rs') ) {
    print join( ",",
        map { "rs" . $_->att('rsId') } $rs->children('MergeHistory') ),
        "\t";
    print join( ",",
        map { "b" . $_->att('buildId') } $rs->children('MergeHistory') ),
        "\n";
}
```

Given your sample, this prints:

```
rs56546490,rs386588736  b130,b142
```

Which looks roughly what you wanted?

- We use `findnodes` to iterate `Rs` elements.
- Within each, we use `children` to fetch the `MergeHistory` elements.
- `map` to extract the attribute and concat the `b` or `rs` string on the front.
- `join` to merge it comma separated.

(you could still do the above with twig_handlers if you prefer, by firing the handler on "Rs" instead)